# Add item to XML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an XML file of CDs and I want to add a new CD with title and price  to it using jQuery. How can I do that?

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: No one buys CDs.....sorry, someone had to say it.

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: The number of "Empire Burlesque"-related XML questions on SO is too damn high. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Burlesque+%5Bxml%5D